# How Can I Keep EXP Levels, But Not Items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As of 1.10 You can keep your items with `/gamerule keepinventory true`. A lot of people say remove EXP, and keep items. However, my goal is to keep EXP, but lose items. Is this at all possible? If it takes a plugin, tell me which one. I can't use mods, as this world is a server. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. instead of killing a player, you can just clear the items from his inverntory:

```
/clear [player] [item] [data] [maxCount] [dataTag]
```

The attributes in brackets are optional. In order to clear every player's inventory, use this:

```
/clear @a
```

And to delete 5 dirt blocks from the nearest player's invetory, use this:

```
/clear @p dirt 5
```

For more information on how to use the `/clear` command, visit the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#clear)

If you want also to teleport the players to spawn, just kill them with `/kill @a` (assuming you already have done `/gamerule keepInventory true`)

Comment: @Emeraldimension feel free to hit the gray check mark next to this answer if it helped you! Thanks!